# msLoadFontset(): Unable to access file. Error opening fontset ./fonts/fonts.txt

Tags: mapserver, font

I have made a map from QGIS by using RT MapServer Exporter plugin, and I want to browse it to MapServer, just like this:
https://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/MappingYourData#no1
and the tutorial on the youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WJt0rAyD2xU

However, when I browse it to MapServer, there is always a error:

`msLoadFontset(): Unable to access file. Error opening fontset ./fonts/fonts.txt.`

Someone said "This means that that the map file is requesting for fonts or symbol definition files but that MapServer cannot find those." But where I can download the font file and how I can put it into MapServer?

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is a reference in the .map file to a font file, as below :

```
MAP
  NAME        "mapserver_wms_server"
  IMAGETYPE   JPEG
  FONTSET     "../fonts/fonts.txt"
  UNITS       METERS
```

Either comment that reference or if you want to use specific fonts, then create a text file with reference to those fonts you want to use, check below link :  http://mapserver.org/mapfile/fontset.html

*Sample for content of font.txt file:*

> Arial    Arial.ttf
>   sans  Vera.ttf

And copy the fonts files you are using in your .map file from *C:\Windows\Fonts* to **fonts** folder .

Comment: Yes I have check the website, but I do not know how to make the font,txt, should I just copy the "arial arial.ttf" into a .txt file? Because I have tried that and it shows "msLoadFontset(): Unable to access file. Error opening fontset C:\Users\lijiao\Desktop\work\fonts.txt."

Comment: did you try to comment the font  reference in .map file ?

Comment: It is better to create **fonts** folder in same folder of .map file and refer to it like this:  **FONTSET     "fonts/fonts.txt"**

Comment: I didn't comment the font reference, how to do that? And what's the content in the font.txt? I can write it by myself or I need to download from internet?

Comment: Either you can remove the line from header in the .map file or comment it using hash at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I'd do it:

Create a file called `fontset.lst` with content like below with paths pointing to the location of the fonts in your system:

```
arial C:\Windows\Fonts\Arial.ttf
arialuni C:\Windows\Fonts\ARIALUNI.TTF
esricaves2 C:\Windows\Fonts\esri_376.ttf
fradm C:\Windows\Fonts\FRADM.TTF
khmer C:\Windows\Fonts\KhmerUI.ttf
opensym C:\Windows\Fonts\opens___.ttf
sc C:\Windows\Fonts\DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf
scb C:\Windows\Fonts\DejaVuSansCondensed-Bold.ttf
sym C:\Windows\Fonts\symbol.ttf
verdana C:\Windows\Fonts\verdana.ttf
```

I use the same file with multiple map services so put it in a location with my other default templates, so my directory structure is like:

```
c:\myServices
+--- myApps
+---+--- test
+---+---+--- DefaultMapIncludes
+---+---+---+---+ fontset.lst
+---+---+--- MapApp1
+---+---+---+---+ MyMapFile.map
```

Then in MyMapFile I reference the `fontset.lst` like:

```
FONTSET "../DefaultMapIncludes/fontset.lst"
```

Comment: I have tried this method and yes, it didn't show the error information, but the map still cannot be shown when I browse it to Mapserver, it is just blank, do you know why?

Comment: Issues relating to blank maps should be explored in another question, if you are no longer getting a font error.  However as a quick check one thing that might be wrong is that there is a mismatch between the LAYER TYPE see [http://mapserver.org/mapfile/layer.html] and the actual type of your data.